# Problem with Intellij and Heap Size Minimum

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jvm, scalaz

I am importing this project

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz

into the Intellij.

But I get a problem with minimum heap size. I am not sure where the size is beeing set. Any advices to fix this problem please:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:34077,suspend=n,server=y -Xdebug -server -Xms3784m -Xmx3784m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Xss4m -Xmx1536M -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar
```

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What are your settings if you open this project in intellij?

Answer (score 2):

In preferences of *Intellij* you can set the maximum heap size for `sbt`:

[image]

This works for me - make sure if you open a new project that you check `Use sbt shell` `for imports` and `for builds`. See my default settings in the screenshot.

Comment: I am knowing the answer now. In the scalaz folder, it have .jvmopts file where it is having 3287m for minmium heap memory size. I am changed this to 1000m and intellij is ok now. thank you for you advices.

Comment: when a maximum heap size is set by .jvmopts, it's better to remove the value in the IntelliJ sbt options.